# pending COMMIT/ROLLBACK with django-bitcoin

Tags: python, django, bitcoin, bitcoind

I'm using django-bitcoin with a project and everything was fine till today... now when i try to create a wallet i get this error :

```
In [3]: master_wallet, created = Wallet.objects.get_or_create(label="master_wallet")

In [4]: radress= master_wallet.receiving_address(fresh_addr=False)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TransactionManagementError                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-b5b750de023b> in <module>()
----> 1 radress= master_wallet.receiving_address(fresh_addr=False)

/Users/gh0st/Documents/apps/django-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_bitcoin/models.pyc in receiving_address(self, fresh_addr)
    361             if usable_addresses.count():
    362                 return usable_addresses[0].address
--> 363             addr = new_bitcoin_address()
    364             updated = BitcoinAddress.objects.select_for_update().filter(Q(id=addr.id) & Q(active=True) & Q(least_received__lte=0) & Q(wallet__isnull=True))\
    365                           .update(active=True, wallet=self)

/Users/gh0st/Documents/apps/django-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_bitcoin/models.pyc in new_bitcoin_address()
    121                     return bp
    122                 else:
--> 123                     print "wallet transaction concurrency:", bp.address
    124 
    125 

/Users/gh0st/Documents/apps/django-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/transaction.pyc in __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback)
    391 
    392     def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
--> 393         self.exiting(exc_type, self.using)
    394 
    395     def __call__(self, func):

/Users/gh0st/Documents/apps/django-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/transaction.pyc in exiting(exc_type, using)
    434 
    435     def exiting(exc_type, using):
--> 436         leave_transaction_management(using=using)
    437 
    438     return _transaction_func(entering, exiting, using)

/Users/gh0st/Documents/apps/django-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/transaction.pyc in leave_transaction_management(using)
     76     those from outside. (Commits are on connection level.)
     77     """
---> 78     get_connection(using).leave_transaction_management()
     79 
     80 def is_dirty(using=None):

/Users/gh0st/Documents/apps/django-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/__init__.pyc in leave_transaction_management(self)
    313                 self.set_autocommit(not managed)
    314             raise TransactionManagementError(
--> 315                 "Transaction managed block ended with pending COMMIT/ROLLBACK")
    316 
    317         if managed == self.get_autocommit():

TransactionManagementError: Transaction managed block ended with pending COMMIT/ROLLBACK
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, i solved the problem. It was an issue with the bitcoind deamon, who stopped with no reason ! after restarting the bitcoind everything was running fine...